# difficulty understanding objective c code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have been trying to implement the [follow code](https://github.com/mauriciomeirelles/FloripaBus/blob/master/FloripaBus/FLBManager.m) , but I am having a hard time understanding the following code:

```
- (void)getRoutesWithStopName:(NSString *) stopName
            success:(void (^)(NSArray *routes))success
            error:(void (^)(NSString *errorMsg)) error
{

    [[self AFManagerObject] POST:GET_ROUTES
       parameters:@{@"params" : @{ @"stopName":    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%",[stopName lowercaseString]]} }
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
              NSArray *routesRows = responseObject[@"rows"];
              NSMutableArray *routes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:routesRows.count];

              for(NSDictionary *dicRoute in routesRows)
              {
                  FLBRoute *route = [[FLBRoute alloc] initWithAttrs:dicRoute];
                  [routes addObject:route];
              }

              success(routes);

          }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err) {
              error(err.description);
          }
     ];

}
```

I tried learning about blocks but I still can not understand what is going on here. Can you provide me a step by step explanation of the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read a little more about callbacks https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming) and blocks https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html
Basically the method send a POST request and as you know it needs some time for the request to be sent to the server and for the server to respond. You don't want in this time your application to be freezed, so 2 callbacks are used, 1 for success case and 1 for failure case. A block callback is just a block of code that you want to be executed later, when the server will respond back, being a success or failure.

Answer (score 2):

actually here used for `webserviceCall`

**step-1**

```
- (void)getRoutesWithStopName:(NSString *) stopName
        success:(void (^)(NSArray *routes))success
        error:(void (^)(NSString *errorMsg)) error
```

// here pass the one `NSString` and get the response using `NSArray` and failure using `NSString`

**step-2**

// here used `AFNEtworking` for call `web service`

```
//request block
```

`[self AFManagerObject]` -- `NSObject` class for `AFNetworking` method place.

POST:GET_ROUTES  --> post is default function of request Type,  GET_ROUTES  --> `your Macro class for Request URL`

```
parameters --> send the parameter to server

[[self AFManagerObject] POST:GET_ROUTES
   parameters:@{@"params" : @{ @"stopName":    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%",[stopName lowercaseString]]} }
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
{
 /***********  success response serlize and store into Array**********/

  NSArray *routesRows = responseObject[@"rows"];
          NSMutableArray *routes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:routesRows.count];

          for(NSDictionary *dicRoute in routesRows)
          {
              FLBRoute *route = [[FLBRoute alloc] initWithAttrs:dicRoute];
              [routes addObject:route];
              // this is your NSObject class for save the details , 
          }

          success(routes);

      /**************  success stop **********/

   }
  /***********  error if request is fail ************/
  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err) {
          error(err.description);
      }
 ];
   /***********  error if request is stop ************/
```

Comment: Adding to Anbu's answer, here's an Objective-C cheat sheet which you may find helpful. http://www.raywenderlich.com/4872/objective-c-cheat-sheet-and-quick-reference

Comment: @AdrianB -- tanx bro ,

Comment: this is fine, would u need any assistance bro

Comment: the block default comes underwith in afnetwork , in that projct we commnly used / created the one class and access this function in over all project